# Can not install zoom conferencing by dpkg

Tags: installation, ubuntu-14.04, dpkg

I've download zoom_amd64.deb by

```
wget -c https://zoom.us/client/latest/zoom_amd64.deb
```

and trying to install it:

```
sudo dpkg -i zoom_amd64.deb
```

but getting:

```
dpkg-deb: error: archive 'zoom_amd64.deb' has premature member
 'control.tar.xz' before 'control.tar.gz', giving up
dpkg: error processing archive zoom_amd64.deb (--install):
 subprocess dpkg-deb --control returned error exit status 2
Errors were encountered while processing:
 zoom_amd64.deb
```

GDebi gives the same error.

Decision from https://askubuntu.com/a/1100361/327339 also does not help.

My OS: Linux vnbs 3.16.0-41-generic #57~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Thu Jun 18 18:01:13 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Please help me to install Zoom Conferencing client on Ubuntu 14.04.

Answer (score 3):

```
sudo apt-get install libxcb-xtest0
```

Comment: Welcome to Super User! While this may answer the question, it would be a better answer if you could provide some explanation **why** it does so.

Answer (score 0):

I have used the below command on Ubuntu 20.10 and works for me.

> sudo apt install libgl1-mesa-glx libxcb-xtest0